# Atmega328p timer wrong configuration

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, avr

I have problem with interrupt on my Atmega328p. I use Arduino Nano 16 Mhz 5V, so it shoudn't be a hardware problem.
This is my code:

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>

volatile uint16_t counter;

int main(void)
{
    DDRB |= (1<<PB5);

    TCCR1B |= (1 << CS10);          // set prescaler to 1
    TIMSK1 |= (1 << TOIE1);         // set overflow interrupt
    sei();                          // enable interrupts


    while (1)
    {
        // Main loop
    }
}

ISR (TIMER1_OVF_vect)
{
    counter++;
    if (counter > 200)
    {
        counter = 0;
        PORTB ^= _BV(PB5);
    }
}
```

I want to have intterupt as often as possible, but with this configuration diode blinks every 1 second - this is too slow, I need at least every 10us or less if it is possible. It can be any other Timer, I don't care.

Answer (score 0):

Timer 1 is a 16-bit timer, which means that in normal mode it overflows at a rate of about 244Hz. Add in the fact that you only flip the LED state every 201 overflows and you get a blink rate of 0.6Hz. If you want to blink at a rate of 100kHz then you need to switch to CTC/OCRA mode (mode 4) with a TOP of 79 and use the output compare interrupt instead. Or you could use mode 14 or 15 instead, and set TOP to 159 and the OC register to an appropriate value and not have to worry about the interrupt at all.

Comment: Could you show me proper code? I'm newbie and I don't understand everything. If you write code for me, I will check it with datasheet to see what is what. I write this code: http://pastebin.com/sR8CrZfk and led change state every ~400us, but I don't know how change it into interrupt ((TCNT0 >= 100) is only to slow it down becuse I have old oscilloscope)

Answer (score 0):

you better use the CTC mode of the timer, for that set the OCR register to some value that makes your interrupt at 10us and change from the Overflow interruot t othe Compare interrupt, something like this:

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>

volatile uint16_t counter;

int main(void)
{
    DDRB |= (1<<PB5);
    OCR1A = 80-1; // at 16MHz you need 160 cycles to reach 10us pulse...
    TCCR1A = 0; // no output compare and WGM1 to 00
    TCCR1B |= (1 << WGM12)|(1 << CS10); // set prescaler to 1 and CTC mode
    TIMSK1 |= (1 << OCIE1A);         // set compare A interrupt
    sei();                          // enable interrupts


    while (1)
    {
        // Main loop
    }
}

ISR (TIMER1_COMPA_vect) // check this too
{ // what was the counter stuff for? it only made things slower...
    PORTB ^= _BV(PB5);
  // keep the ISR as quick as posible, it takes about 1us gettin' in & out
}
```

I'm only thinking if OCRA should be 80 exactly, or as I remember, it should be 79...

Comment: Since it *toggles* on interrupt you need to halve the compare value (since you are counting half the period).